# Titanium: How to redirect from external to internal URL in webview

Tags: ios, redirect, webview, titanium, appcelerator

So I know how to access both external and internal URL's in the Titanium Webview. But I have no idea how to redirect from an external url to the internal url.

I've got a file called "index.html" in the root folder, so for the webview this should work to access it:

```
Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'index.html'
});
```

External urls are pretty straight forward

```
Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
});
```

However, when on the external url, how do I redirect to this local file? None of these work:

```
 <a href="file://index.html">LOCAL?</a>
 <a href="file:///index.html">LOCAL?</a>
```

or the javascript variant

```
window.location = 'file:///index.html';
```

Any clues on how to do this?

Comment: Just wondering what value will you get if webView.evalJS('someFunctionToPrintout(window.location);'); when the webView is opening local file index.html 



Will that give you the right path to the local file?

Comment: I'm getting the full path to the file, `file://Users/username/[..]/index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered, in the end, are 2 possibilities to achieve this. But it can't be done through redirection.

One: Poll for a certain variable using the `webview.evalJS()` function

```
var my_data = $.login_webview.evalJS('global.data;');
```

Of course, it works only with strings, not with objects. So if you're passing JSON, make sure it is set as a string!

Two: Do an actual redirection server side, to another serverside page and monitor for URL change and then do `evalJS()` once again, but no need for polling

```
$.login_webview.addEventListener('load',function(e){
if (e.url.indexOf('mobile/redirect.php') > -1){
    var my_data = $.login_webview.evalJS('global.data');
    }
 });
```

Just make sure, with **2** that you're actually setting the required data in Javascript using server side technology.